# xcode - photos framework - error in contentMode

Tags: xcode, swift

```
let assests : PHAsset = self.asset[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset
    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(assests, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFit , options: nil, resultHandler: {(result : UIImage!, info:NSDictionary!)in
            cell.setThumbnailImage(result)
```

Here this code gets the image from the image data that is acquired from the PHFetchResult

```
contentMode: .AspectFit
```

is where everything is going wrong. IDE says there's no member .AspectFit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter type of resultHandler is wrong.
Use `[NSObject : AnyObject]!` instead `NSDictionary!`. So signature of `requestImageForAsset()` method is wrong. That's why the type prediction does not work correctly.

Like below:

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(assests, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: nil, resultHandler: { (result: UIImage!, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) in

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no `.AspectFit` member for `UIViewContentMode`.

You can try `.ScaleAspectFit`

Comment: that's PHImageContentMode, not UIViewContentMode